# Mock Multi-Processing in Unit test and checking the number of times the mock is invoked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I saw the below function provided for mocking multi-processing call in python

```
class MockPoolApplyResult:
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        self._func = func
        self._args = args

    def get(self, timeout=0):
        return self._func(*self._args)

monkeypatch.setattr("multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap",
                lambda self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None:
                MockPoolApplyResult(func, args))
```

What does the below lambda function do and how can I check the number of times it is called?

```
monkeypatch.setattr("multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap",
                lambda self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None:
                MockPoolApplyResult(func, args))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda is equivalent to this:

```py
def mock_starmap(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None):
    return MockPoolApplyResult(func, args)

monkeypatch.setattr("multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap", mock_starmap)
```

It replaces the `starmap` method on the `Pool` class object [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L366) with a function that takes the exact same arguments.

The intended behavior is probably that when you have `my_pool = Pool(3)` and run `my_pool.starmap(myfunc, [1,2,3]); my_pool.get()` it would execute `myfunc(1)`, `myfunc(2)` and `myfunc(3)` within the current process, as opposed to these calls being performed by processes in the pool. But it looks like it will actually call `myfunc(1, 2, 3)` because of how `MockPoolApplyResult.get()` is written.

**Edit.** Forgot to answer part 2 of your question: you can't trace the number of calls to a monkeypatched function. For this you'll need to *mock* the starmap function instead, and then the mocked object will track the number of calls. You can do this either using the built-in `unittest.mock` module directly or with the [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) wrapper package.